# Passing a function expression into new Function() with a variable

Tags: javascript, function

This is the most confusing thing ever. The title probably doesn't make much sense. I did my best. Hope I can be clear.
Ok i am looking at the tic-tac-toe example from google channel api.

in the javascript portion.

they have something like this;

```
sendMessage = function(param) {
  alert(param);
  //this part actually sends message to server, 
  //for simplicity lets assume it pops up alert.    
  }

init = function(){
  var input = 3;
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
  submitButton.onclick = new Function('sendMessage(' + input + ')');
}

setTimeout(init, 100);
```

this pops up an alert and prints 3. I am not sure how this works. But it works. If one can explain that, that would be great too. I could not find anywhere else use of new Function() like this.

The problem is, if the input is a string,

```
var input = "test";
```

this does not work, and there is no alert that pops up.

thanks for any explanation and help.

Comment: It works, and it's extremely ugly. Are you sure Google recommends that, and not w3schools? Hint: `Function()`~~`eval()`

Comment: well look it up for yourself. thats what they did.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/channel-tac-toe/source/browse/trunk/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Function` constructor works by `eval`uating its argument as a function body.

```
... = new Function('sendMessage(' + input + ')');
```

is similar to

```
... = eval("function(){sendMessage("+input+")}";
```

For numeric `input`s, this works, since their textual representation works as a numeric literal. For textual inputs, it doesn't. A limited support can be gained by doing

```
... = new Function('sendMessage("'+input+'")');
```

A more general way would be to use

```
... = new Function('sendMessage("'+JSON.stringify(input)+'")');
```

However, I recommend using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) instead to avoid any form of `eval` and the dependence on the `JSON` object, which does not exist in very old browsers (IE<8):

```
... = (function(input){
  return function(){
    sendMessage(input)
  }
})(input)
```

Or, if the `input` variable doesn't change, you don't need to capture its value:

```
... = function(){ sendMessage(input) }
```

Or, if you don't use `this` inside sendMessage, you can use `bind` (IE8 needs shimming):

```
... = sendMessage.bind(undefined, input)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the input is a string, the function call becomes :

```
sendMessage(string)
```

which should actually be :

`sendMessage("string")` or  `sendMessage('string')`

```
sendMessage = function(param) {
  alert(param);   
  }

init = function(){
  var input = '"string"';
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
  submitButton.onclick = new Function('sendMessage(' + input + ')');
}

setTimeout(init, 100);
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xUeLn/) to see how you could use.

Comment: So you should be setting `var input = "'text'";`

Comment: it works. but i still dont get how new Function() works like that. the argument is supposed to be the function body. how is 'sendMessage(' + input + ')' is the function body?

Comment: You are actually casting & invoking sendMessage as a Function.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter to function gets evaluated.. that is to say it is executed. that's why it works.

when you pass a string it didnt work simply because that string you pass will be treated as an object or a variable instead of a string.. and we all know it doesnt exist.

i.e

this works:

```
submitButton.onclick = new Function('sendMessage(3)');
```

this does not:

```
submitButton.onclick = new Function('sendMessage(test)'); //because test does not exist
```

but this will

```
submitButton.onclick = new Function('sendMessage("test")');
```

so if you change your code to:

```
submitButton.onclick = new Function('sendMessage("' + input + '")');
```

then all is well